# How to get notification when user connects to bluetooth device in IOS settings?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

sorry for my bad english

I am developing an app on IOS 9.2. One of the app functions is to get information about bluetooth devices.
I have already managed to monitor bluetooth devices nearby using CoreBluetooth framework and connect to one of them. It works in background mode too. The problem is how to get notification when user connects to device from IOS settings?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You cannot get notifications of BLE connections that are not initiated by your app nor legacy Bluetooth devices if they are not associated with your app through MFi/External Accessory support. The AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification will fire if the user changes the audio route as a result of connecting a Bluetooth audio device and you can also examine the available inputs and outputs to determine if a Bluetooth audio device is connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is clear now